# Вставка звукового файла в консольное приложение на C#

Tags: c#, аудио, консоль

Можно ли в Visual Studio на C# в консольном приложении вставить звуковой файл, который будет проигрываться после (хотя желательно одновременно, но и так сойдет) выполнения команды Console.WriteLine? И если да, то как это сделать, и как сделать так, чтобы после сборки релизной версии приложения этот файл без проблем проигрывался и это приложение можно было бы спокойно переносить на другой компьютер?

Answer (score 4):

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\mywavfile.wav");
player.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам неважно, какой звук будет проигрываться, то есть метод [Console.Beep();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4fe3hdb1(v=vs.110).aspx)